# TinyMCE - How to auto display a template

Tags: templates, tinymce

Is there a way to have a template be used automatically, be default, right when the TinyMCE box first loads with the page?
This would be useful so you don't have to give the user instructions on how to find/use a particular template.

I have tried looking online and at the TinyMCE documentation but nothing is jumping out at me as a way to make this happen.